# how to add a column after another one in monetDB

Tags: monetdb

I am trying to add a new column in a monetDB database and I want it positioned after a specific one. In `mysql` this is possible using the `AFTER` keyword.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(255) AFTER myOtherColumn
```

I am trying this in the `mclient`:

```
sql>ALTER TABLE dbname.table_name ADD COLUMN new_name AFTER existing_name SET DEFAULT NULL;
```

What I get is a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected AFTER in: "ALTER TABLE dbname.table_name ADD COLUMN new_name AFTER"
```

It is true that the [ALTER documentation](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/Alter) does not specify that `AFTER` exists, but I am hoping that anybody knows an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe way is to create an new table with the columns properly ordered and move the data; you probably know this already.
However if you really cannot do that, create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW AS SELECT [order the columns however you want here] FROM your_table;
```